# fputs returns -1 after reading to the end of the file

Tags: c, file-io, stream

I'm having some problems with file write failures on Windows. I simplified it down to this example:

```
FILE* f = fopen("test.out", "r+b");
fseek(f, -1, SEEK_END); // one byte before the end
printf("read byte: %c\n", fgetc(f)); // read the last byte; now at the end
printf("attempting write: %d\n", fputs("text", f));
```

This correctly outputs the last byte of `test.out`, but the `fputs` fails and returns -1. These similar examples all work fine:

- Don't read

  ```
  FILE* f = fopen("test.out", "r+b");
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END); // this is where I ended up after the fgetc() above
  printf("attempting write: %d\n", fputs("text", f));
  ```
- Seek to the end after reading (even though we're already there)

  ```
  FILE* f = fopen("test.out", "r+b");
  fseek(f, -1, SEEK_END);
  printf("read byte: %c\n", fgetc(f));
  fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
  printf("attempting write: %d\n", fputs("text", f));
  ```
- Seek to exactly where we already are

  ```
  FILE* f = fopen("test.out", "r+b");
  fseek(f, -1, SEEK_END);
  printf("read byte: %c\n", fgetc(f));
  fseek(f, ftell(f), SEEK_SET);
  printf("attempting write: %d\n", fputs("text", f));
  ```
- Read, but not the very last byte

  ```
  FILE* f = fopen("test.out", "r+b");
  fseek(f, -2, SEEK_END); // two bytes before the end
  printf("read byte: %c\n", fgetc(f)); // read the penultimate byte
  printf("attempting write: %d\n", fputs("text", f));
  ```
- Read *past the end* (...)

  ```
  FILE* f = fopen("test.out", "r+b");
  fseek(f, -1, SEEK_END); // one byte before the end
  printf("read byte: %c\n", fgetc(f)); // read the last byte; now at the end
  printf("read byte: %c\n", fgetc(f)); // read a garbage byte
  printf("attempting write: %d\n", fputs("text", f));
  ```

These all seem to indicate a stream error or eof problem, but `ferror(f)` and `feof(f)` both return 0 up until the failed `fputs()`. After, `ferror(f)` is non-zero, but `errno` is 0, so I don't know what the issue is

I see this on Windows only, in both Visual Studio 2008 and GCC 4.7.2 (MinGW). On Linux the same code runs without errors

Comment: Maybe the error is because it is opened as read-only.

Comment: "r+" allows writes too.

Comment: @PeterL. "r+" is "Open for reading and writing"; if that were the case none of the working examples I posted would work

Comment: Is the errno value different if you *don't nest* the fputs and the printf?

Comment: @Jens No, it's still 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The C standard requires that you do a seek when switching from "read mode" to "write mode" or vice versa, except after certain other special cases which are normally not worth enumerating.

An implementation (such as the one I wrote years ago for the BSDs, or the Linux one) can be more forgiving than required, making your code "just work".  (It's really quite easy, you just need, inside the implementation, to keep two separate counters instead of a single combined counter.)  But the Standard does not require that the implementation be friendly, and the Windows one is not.

Comment: Ah, yes. For future reference, C99 7.19.5.3 #6: "When a ﬁle is opened with update mode (**'+'** as the second or third character in the above list of **mode** argument values), both input and output may be performed on the associated stream. However, output shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to the **fflush** function or to a ﬁle positioning function (**fseek**, **fsetpos**, or **rewind**), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an intervening call to a ﬁle positioning function, unless the input operation encounters end-of-ﬁle."